# How to fix Timezone in php

Tags: php, json

Im using PHP and Json to get data for login and register user in Android, When I request to server by Json, I received the result following as:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone  settings. 
You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in <b>C:\AppServ\www\DemoApp\DBOperations.php</b> on line <b>114</b><br />
{"result":"success","message":"Check your mail for reset password code."}
```

How to fix timezone in PHP?

Comment: Are you using a frameworks ?

Comment: Hi @Snoobie: Im using AppServ and PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the notice you got there? It's pretty explanatory:

> You are **required** to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

If you don't want to set the timezone in your php.ini file, you can use the `date_default_timezone_set` function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

For example.